# How to render a non-public Facebook story with user token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'd like to "render" in Facebook style some stories from my users.

Using EMBEDDED POSTS (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts) you can use SDK to render a story with the URL

https://www.facebook.com/{fb_user_id}/posts/{fb_post_id}

This works just with just public posts, those user has marked as "visible for everyone", the problem comes with those user marked just for his friends.

But I have the user's token, and I can access the content of this story through Open Graph with:
http://graph.facebook.com/{post_id}?access_token={token}

but this returns an array with data, not the "Facebook style box" as you get when embedding as explained before.

And I want a render of the Facebook story as they have in their page, I can not "make" the HTML since there's a lot of combinations (feed, stories, albums, comments, videos ...) , that's the reason of the embedded story widget.

Is there any way to get a Facebook styled box as they usually render stories, for stories that are not public but you (as developer) has access since you have the user's token ?

Comment: So you want to render a story that the user are not allowed to see?

Comment: No, I want to render a story that user has not PUBLIC to EVERYONE, but his friends, but I (as developer) have the token to get the story information through Open Graph

Comment: Well, there is no way to get the “Facebook layout” without creating the HTML structure yourself. The purpose of an API is to give access to data, not to rendered output. If users want the latter, they have an easy choice: Visit Facebook.